# Coinbase API just lists BTC account - local currency: Account not found

Tags: bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to get the balance from my local currency account via the Coinbase API, but I can not call up the account at all.

The general command "client.get_accounts()" just returns the BTC account. According to documentation it should list all accounts, what would include my local currency account (with money in it).

The command for a specific account "client.get_account()" returns "coinbase.wallet.error.NotFoundError: APIError(id=not_found): Account not found".
I got the ID for the account from https://www.coinbase.com/accounts/. The BTC ID on this page is the same as from the API call client.get_accounts().

If I try to call the ETH wallet I get the same error.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

This one can be a problem related to the API authorizations. If you go to the API settings page (https://www.coinbase.com/settings/api) you should find if the API Key and Secrets have access to all the accounts or not.

As for me, the `client.get_accounts()` returns all the wallets, so from there you can fetch the ID of the wallet you want to get more info from and pass it as parameter to `client.get_account()`